# Reports do not work because of timezone on Magento

Tags: magento, timezone, report

I’ve tried several solutions available on forums and sites with tutorials, but none managed to solve my problem.

The sales reports are not displayed and I always get the message that I need to update statistics if the **time zone** has been changed.
I have already updated all the statistics, I changed the timezone in the admin and also in `app/etc/config.xml` (America / Sao_Paulo), but without success.

Please, I need to deliver this shop urgently this week.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide the specific parts of your config.xml and the exact error message you are receiving.   From what you posted so far, all I can see is that you have extra spaces in your time zone id - but I'm not sure if that is what is in your config file, or just how you typed it here.  There should be no spaces.  It should just be `America/Sao_Paulo`.

Answer (score 2):

I really doubt it is still useful for you to know the solution to the problem considering the amount of time since the date of publication. It may be interesting for other people anyways, so here it goes:

Even though the notice saying 'This report depends on timezone configuration. Once timezone is changed, the lifetime statistics need to be refreshed. Last updated: 15/10/2013 12:25:34. To refresh last day's statistics, click here.' claims to refresh statistics, it does NOT. The propper way to get it to work is by going to Reports->Refresh Statistics from the Admin Panel. Then all there is to do is selecting all items and refreshing them.

That is a neat solution that, unlike many others, avoid touching Magento's code.

Comment: I have tried this solution but it still does not generate the accurate report. It is still basing on GMT time.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no any major issue in your magento then Refresh Life Time Statistic will probably fix the issue.